# Can't get a parameter in a JsonObject

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get the phone number (telefono) that is in `custom_fields`.
I am calling as an object customfield and apparently is an arraylist. 
as I can get that parameter, as part customfield phone brings other parameters such as mail, map

```
"posts":[
    {
        "id": 4121,
        "custom_fields": {
            "correo": [ 
                 "test@test.cl" 
            ],
            "telefono": [ 
                "98997876"  
            ]
    }
```

I phone in custom field but I can't get it, do I get the other data smoothly
Code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

Locales = jsonObj.getJSONArray(POST);

for (int i = 0; i < Locales.length(); i++) 
{
    JSONObject c = Locales.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_CUSTOM);
    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_TELEFONO);

    HashMap<String, String> LocalesMAP = new HashMap<String, String>();

    LocalesMAP.put(TAG_ID, id);
    LocalesMAP.put(TAG_TELEFONO, mobile);

    LocalesList.add(LocalesMAP);
}
```

Comment: `phone.getJSONArray("telefono")[0]` should do it if there is only 1 number (otherwise it gets the first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String TAG_TELEFONO = "telefono";           
JSONArray array = phone.getJSONArray(TAG_TELEFONO);
if(array.length() > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        //Toast.makeText(context, "we got " + array.getString(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("TEST", "we got " + array.getString(i));
}
```

Tell me what do you see when you run this ?

Comment: `.make(context, ` red brand

Comment: `context` I still ticking red

Comment: replace it with your context, I don't have your source code -.-

Comment: solve it and found the solution, but now I have another error

Comment: Accept this answer and start a new question

Comment: link me to the new questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853030/obtain-parameters-of-a-jsonobject-within-another-jsonobject